# How do I solve spin-clouddriver-57bdcf65fd-dm5mq and spin-clouddriver-57bdcf65fd-fpqh9 errors while building an AWS AMI using packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, packer, spinnaker

When I build an AWS AMI using packer I am getting `spin-clouddriver-57bdcf65fd-dm5mq and spin-clouddriver-57bdcf65fd-fpqh9` errors. I am using this template.json file

```
{
    "variables": {
        "aws_access_key": "",
        "aws_secret_key": ""
},
    "builders": [
    {
        "type": "amazon-ebs",
        "region": "us-west-2",
        "source_ami": "ami-0e34e7b9ca0ace12d",
        "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
        "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
        "ssh_username": "ec2-user",
        "instance_type": "t3a.xlarge",
        "launch_block_device_mappings": [ {
          "device_name": "/dev/sda1",
          "volume_size": 64
      } 
    ],
        "ami_name": "minnakeramitwo - {{timestamp}}"
    }
   ],
    "provisioners": [
    {
        "type": "file",
        "source": "minnaker.tgz",
        "destination": "/tmp/minnaker.tgz"
    },
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "inline": ["tar -xzvf /tmp/minnaker.tgz && cd minnaker && ./scripts/install.sh -o"]
   }
]
}
```

and the following pods are not running file for the error attached below as well

```
amazon-ebs: spin-clouddriver-57bdcf65fd-fq2xs   0/1     Evicted   0          4m
amazon-ebs: spin-clouddriver-57bdcf65fd-4pkc7   0/1     Evicted   0          4m
amazon-ebs: spin-clouddriver-57bdcf65fd-w5sh2   0/1     Evicted   0          3m59s
amazon-ebs: spin-gate-78d9797f5c-nvmg9          0/1     Evicted   0          15m
amazon-ebs: spin-clouddriver-57bdcf65fd-p2qz4   0/1     Evicted   0          3m58s
amazon-ebs: spin-gate-78d9797f5c-gzf9h          0/1     Evicted   0          3m58s
amazon-ebs: spin-clouddriver-57bdcf65fd-4klhb   0/1     Evicted   0          3m57s
amazon-ebs: spin-clouddriver-57bdcf65fd-55k44   0/1     Pending   0          3m56s
amazon-ebs: spin-gate-78d9797f5c-2bsjc          0/1     Evicted   0          3m57s
amazon-ebs: spin-gate-78d9797f5c-2ptrz          0/1     Pending   0          3m56s
```

Comment: Please format the error code/logs properly as well. You can use the same symbol you use to format your code.

Comment: please give more details: where are you running Spinnaker? have you configured the AWS Provider successfully? share you `hal config` output.
Thanks